# Need advices or solutions of how to make html structure according to design?

Tags: html, css

It has happen that a newbie designer decided to make site with a lot of rhombus ideas. So here is the next idea of design: [image]

Any ideas how to make structure of it?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Paulie_D, if you can help me to ask a correct looking question - help me so. I dont know how to make a prettier question according to the topic.

Comment: I refer you to my comments above. SO is not for general guidance but **specific, solvable** programming issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to structure this is a list, if only because it seems semantically appropriate and because images and descriptions should be kept together. 
Roughly, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="staff__list--left">
        <name>
        <role>
        <description>
        <image>
    </li>
    <li class="staff__list--right">
        <name>
        <role>
        <description>
        <image>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the floating li having position:relative and a width like calc(50% - [image size]) and the image position:absolute so you can move it towards the center. 
I tend to keep the DOM as minimal as possible, but you may want to group name, role and description in their own div if it helps you.

Comment: Image with absolute position... I'd like to avoid absolute. But thank you for idea.

Comment: I hear you but I'm not sure you can have such shapes so close to each other without some absolute positioning. 
You may group name, role and description in a div, then use display:table on the li to avoid have the image on its own, but you'll then need to give position:absolute on the li in order to have the images getting this close.
To me it seems that having the images as absolute gives you more flexibility for the responsiveness.

I guess you can find ways to not use the absolute and not even a list, but I'm afraid this is leading to a code so pixel-perfect it will be harder to maintain.

Comment: CSS Grid could help here (its advantage over flexbox is that it allows some 3D layout z-index-like) but it's not supported enough yet.

I hope you'll find a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I've made according to advises:

```css
html, body  {
  background: #fff !important;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 690px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.specialists li.name {
 color: #e70f73;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
.specialists li.role {
  color: #fab233;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
.specialists {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.specialists:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.specialists:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;  
}

.specialists.left {
  float: left
}
.specialists.right {
  float: right
}
.specialists .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
.specialists.left .image {
  right: -100%;
}
.specialists.right .image {
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
<ul class="specialists left">
  <li class="name">Forest Gamp</li>
  <li class="role">Сharacter, artist</li>
  <li class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque et recusandae placeat maxime quasi nihil. Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/face.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>

<ul class="specialists right">
  <li class="name">Forest Gamp</li>
  <li class="role">Сharacter, artist</li>
  <li class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque et recusandae placeat maxime quasi nihil. Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/face.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="specialists left">
  <li class="name">Forest Gamp</li>
  <li class="role">Сharacter, artist</li>
  <li class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque et recusandae placeat maxime quasi nihil. Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/face.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="specialists right">
  <li class="name">Forest Gamp</li>
  <li class="role">Сharacter, artist</li>
  <li class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque et recusandae placeat maxime quasi nihil. Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/face.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="specialists left">
  <li class="name">Forest Gamp</li>
  <li class="role">Сharacter, artist</li>
  <li class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque et recusandae placeat maxime quasi nihil. Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/face.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>

<ul class="specialists right">
  <li class="name">Forest Gamp</li>
  <li class="role">Сharacter, artist</li>
  <li class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque et recusandae placeat maxime quasi nihil. Dorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li class="image"><img src="http://eyes.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/face.png" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Getting closer. ;) I guess now it's mostly a matter of tweaking pixels here and there. You could work with percentages for less pain when you make this responsive. 
I would do a single list though, not many ul. 
Note that in the mockup the text in the right cards is also right aligned. 
Oh, and that .specialists:not(:first-child) in the CSS can be turned into a simpler .specialists + .specialists so it doesn't break in older browsers.